# Overloaded EC2 Instance?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, overloading

A developer has made me a script to connect my CRM infusionsoft to a Google calendar. When I put through a specific form on my CRM its then added to my Google calendar. The script checks every two minutes for any updates. I set-up a EC2 Amazon Linux instance and put the script on it. The server has gone down twice. The first time it came back again but now I cant access it via SSH. I get this error message:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

​After trying out lots of different fixes, not of which were successful I came to the conclusion that ​maybe the server was being overloaded? I was going to create a new instance and pop the script on their. Can anyone tell me if this is correct? If it is how can I stop the server being overloaded again? Could I increase the MaxStartups value? Will this help? Is there a different value I can increase. I would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: in AWS management console,click the ec2 instance which you can't ssh, go to page `monitoring`, you can see the CPU load diagram. Normally if you can't ssh, the instance is hang, no network, no cpu load.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the Monitoring tab of your instance in the console.  This will show you what is going on with your instance.

Once you figure out what the problem is, you can set up Cloudwatch alerts to let you know when certain events have occurred.